# How to recover the value of another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to get value from a child component (DropDown) and display them in a parent class (App),

I explain, I have a drop-down list that is imported into the App class, when I choose a value in this drop-down list I modify my data that is displayed in my class App,

class App :

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      station: [],
      stationValue: ''
    }
  }

  getParking = async () => {
    try {
      const reponse = await axios.get(URL + "station/");
      this.setState({
        station: reponse.data['hydra:member']
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  };

  getData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(URL + "events?station=station_id");
      this.setState({
        data: response.data["hydra:member"]
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.getParking()

    setInterval(this.appendData, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    const {data, station} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <Dropdown dataStation={station}/>
        </header>
        {
          data.map((item, key) =>
            <div key={key}>
              <>
                {item.label}
              </>
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

composent DropDown :

```
const Dropdown = ({dataStation}) => {
    const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
    const [selectItem, setSelectItem] = useState(showMenu);

    const showList = () => {
      setShowMenu(!showMenu)
    };

    const toggleSelected = (list) => {
      setSelectItem(list.name);
      setShowMenu(false)
    };

    return (
      <>
        <div className="dropdown-list-style" onClick={showList}>
          <div style={{display: 'inline'}}>
            {showMenu
              ? (<div style={{textAlign: 'right'}}><ChevronUp/></div>)
              : (<div style={{textAlign: 'right'}}><ChevronDown/></div>)
            }
            {selectItem}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="dropdown-list-style" style={{display: showMenu ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
          {
            dataStation.map((list, index) =>
              <div key={index} onClick={() => toggleSelected(list)}>
                {list.name}
              </div>
            )
          }
        </div>
      </>
    )};
```

So when I choose for example in the drop-down list the value "A", I will have to display the elements which are in "A", and "A" for example has a Id "1", and this id I will have to recover it and put it in my function (getData) which is in the class A. my code works when I put values ​​written by hand for example when I put directly 1 in place of (station_id), but not when I wish to retrieve the id via the drop-down list.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside your app component make callback that set the station value

```
setStation=(stationValue)=>{
 this.setState({stationValue:stationValue})
}
```

passit to dropdown like this

```
 <Dropdown dataStation={station} setStation={this.setStation}/>
```

inside dorpdow compoenent
uset it on click of item like:

```
 {
        dataStation.map((list, index) =>
          <div key={index} onClick={() =>{toggleSelected(list); props.setStation(list)}}>
            {list.name}
          </div>
        )
      }
```

**EDIT**

you can use Station value in getData url like

```
   getData = async () => {
      try {
  const response = await axios.get(URL + "events?station="+this.state.stationValue);
  this.setState({
    data: response.data["hydra:member"]
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
      };
```

Comment: `setSatation` should be `setStation`?

Comment: @timotgl yes sure

Comment: wow thank you i can get the id ;), but last thing , how can i past this Id in the url?  i need to do a ( this.state.stationValue.id ) in the url?

Comment: @Imrickjames in which url ?? if its is getParking call url then you just need to append from state and same can be done for any other url

Comment: in the url who is in (getData ), i need an id of Stations

Comment: i was try this way, and when i add a console.log of (this.state.parkingValue) in this function i have not response

Comment: edit: the code work now, i was just need to refrest it with a (setInterbal() ) . thanks alot ;)